# Execv Linux printf doesn't work

Tags: c, linux, execv

I'm trying to run executable using this c code:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     printf("hello.\n");
     sleep(2);
     if (execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL) == -1)
          printf("Error occured during execute ls.\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

why printf("hello\n") 
doesn't work? even if i put sleep?

Comment: It works fine for me. Were you redirecting output when you tested it?

Comment: I execute it in terminal. ls works good, but there is no "hello" printed

Answer (score 3):

Your program should work when output is to a terminal, but it will not work correctly if output is redirected to a file or a pipe. When `stdout` is not connected to a terminal, its output is fully buffered. Calling an `exec` function does not flush the buffer before replacing the current process with the new program, so any buffered output will be lost.

Call `fflush(stdout);` before calling `execlp()` and the problem should be resolved. You don't need to sleep, it has no effect on output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     printf("hello.\n");
     fflush(stdout);
     if (execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL) == -1)
          printf("Error occured during execute ls.\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @ILyaShapira You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I can't because i don't have 15 reputation